# NodeJS 3DES ECB encryption does not equal C# encryption

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, 3des, ecb

I'm trying to convert the C# code to encrypt text using 3DES ECB
(You can copy and paste it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ to run it)

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string toEncrypt = "testtext";
        string key = "testkey";
        bool useHashing = true;
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader =
                                                new AppSettingsReader();

        key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String)) : key;

        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else 
        {
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        }

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        key = Convert.ToBase64String(keyArray, 0, keyArray.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

        tdes.Clear();

        Console.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Ihs2jX9fWXhn9SWXHyj/dQ== <- md5 secret key
wHL9J7vhm9LZI2W5DQJGKw== <- encrypt result
```

So I rewrite the above code in NodeJS to use crypto

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const md5 = text => {
  return crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update(text)
    .digest('base64');
}

const encrypt = (text, secretKey) => {
  secretKey = md5(secretKey);
  console.log(secretKey);

  const cipher = crypto.createCipher('des-ede3', secretKey);
  const encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');

  return encrypted + cipher.final('base64');
};
const encrypted = encrypt('testtext', 'testkey');

console.log(encrypted);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Ihs2jX9fWXhn9SWXHyj/dQ== <- md5 secret key
VNa9fDYgPus5IMhUZRI+jQ== <- encrypt result
```

I think the problem lies in C# and NodeJS Crypto approach in using 3DES ECB. Any idea how to replicate the C# code **behaviour** in NodeJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nod3des to replicate the same behavior as C#. In case you're wondering how it works

https://github.com/4y0/nod3des/blob/master/index.js#L30

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var forge    = require('node-forge');
var utf8     = require('utf8');

...

_3DES.encrypt = function (key, text){

    key          = CryptoJS.MD5(utf8.encode(key)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
    key          = key + key.substring(0, 8); 
    var cipher   = forge.cipher.createCipher('3DES-ECB', forge.util.createBuffer(key));
    cipher.start({iv:''});
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(text, 'utf-8'));
    cipher.finish();
    var encrypted = cipher.output; 
    return ( forge.util.encode64(encrypted.getBytes()) );

}
```

Comment: So you've been able to complete your *task*, but does this post *answer* the question you actually asked?

Comment: @AakashM yep, it does, but I cannot accept my own answer within 2 days of posted date. I think the question is "how to replicate the behavior of the C# in NodeJS" instead of how to "convert the C# code to NodeJS", I'll update the question

Comment: plz also post decrypt function.

Answer (score 6):

Triple DES is only defined for 192 bit keys. An MD5 hash only provides 128 bit. There are multiple ways of expanding a potential 128 bit key into a 192 bit key. If we assume that the 128 bit key is made up of two 64 bit sub keys *k1* and *k2*, then C# will create a 192 bit key consisting of *k1*, *k2* and *k1* again.

Here is the code that works:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const md5 = text => {
  return crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update(text)
    .digest();
}

const encrypt = (text, secretKey) => {
  secretKey = md5(secretKey);
  console.log(secretKey.toString('base64'));
  secretKey = Buffer.concat([secretKey, secretKey.slice(0, 8)]); // properly expand 3DES key from 128 bit to 192 bit

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', secretKey, '');
  const encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');

  return encrypted + cipher.final('base64');
};
const encrypted = encrypt('testtext', 'testkey');

console.log(encrypted);
```

The other issue that you had was using `crypto#createCipher` instead of `crypto#createCipheriv`. The former has an additional hashing of the "key" which you don't want in this case.

---

Other potential problems:

- **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.
- **Don't use Triple DES nowadays.** It only provides at best 112 bit of security even if you use the largest key size of 192 bit. If a shorter key size is used, then it only provides 56 or 57 bits of security. AES would be faster (processors have a special AES-NI instruction set) and even more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with 3DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).
- You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, yes regarding the ECB mode, it's a requirement from my employer business partner. I told them to use AES but they prefer to use ECB for a reason that I cannot state here.

Comment: how decrypt now ?

Comment: @JaikeySarraf Basically the same code, just changing `createCipheriv` to `createDecipheriv`, but as I said, this would only do ECB mode without an IV which is pretty insecure.

Comment: correct, we are changing but we dont want to message our customer to change secret details or reenter, so first we decrypt all and than we will use PKBDF2, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a different requirement (CBC) and I thought of adding it here in case it helps anyone looking for another solution. The code is below, but if needs more details on the context, check this gist: [gist](https://gist.github.com/dtiziani/30d3950353f8301fd9545721bd656fb3)

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

/**
 * This class is an implementation to encrypt/decrypt 3DES encrypted from .NET
 */
export class TripleDESCryptoHelper {
  // Encryption algorithm
  private static readonly algorithm = 'des-ede-cbc';
  /**
   * Decrypts a value encrypted using 3DES Algorithm.
   *
   * @param encryptionKey Key used for encryption
   * @param encryptedValue Value to be decrypted
   * @returns string containing the value (ascii)
   */
  static decrypt(encryptionKey: string, encryptedValue: string): string {
    const keyHash = crypto
      .createHash('md5')
      .update(encryptionKey)
      .digest();
    const iv = keyHash.slice(0, 8);

    const encrypted = Buffer.from(encryptedValue, 'base64');
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(TripleDESCryptoHelper.algorithm, keyHash, iv);
    const decoded = decipher.update(encrypted, undefined, 'ascii') + decipher.final('ascii');

    return decoded;
  }

  /**
   * Encrypts a value using 3DES Algorithm.
   *
   * @param encryptionKey Key used for encryption
   * @param encryptedText The text to be encrypted
   */
  static encrypt(encryptionKey: string, encryptedText: string): string {
    const keyHash = crypto
      .createHash('md5')
      .update(encryptionKey)
      .digest();
    const iv = keyHash.slice(0, 8);

    const encrypted = Buffer.from(encryptedText);

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(TripleDESCryptoHelper.algorithm, keyHash, iv);
    const encoded = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(encrypted), cipher.final()]);
    const encodedAsBase64 = encoded.toString('base64');

    return encodedAsBase64;
  }
}
```